# Django unique_together() for field1 and field2 and vice versa (field2 and field1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

It's possible to create duplicate thread with same first_person and second_person using unique_together() in django.

```
class Meta:
        unique_together = ['first_person', 'second_person']
```

But just like that,
Is it possible to make it work for same second_person and first_person too ?

For example if first_person is abc@gmail.com and second_person is xyz@gmail.com then I can't create duplicate value but if I try to make second_person is abc@gmail.com  and first_person is xyz@gmail.com then it again creates thread with same person that I dont want. Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Since [django-4.1](/questions/tagged/django-4.1), you can use functional uniqness filters (and indexes) with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint), and you thus can determine the lower and greater item:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest, Least

# …


class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                Least('first_person', 'second_person'),
                Greatest('first_person', 'second_person'),
                name='asymetrical_friends',
            )
        ]
```

---

> **Note**: As the [documentation on **`unique_together`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) says, the `unique_together` constraint will likely become deprecated. The documentation advises to use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) from Django's [*constraint
> framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have used your UniqueConstraint code and I got the following error :
`TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given`

Comment: @sodmzs1: this works since Django-4.1. Likely you use an earlier version.

Comment: Oh yes! I am using Django 3.0.5. Can't we have something for this version.

Comment: @sodmzs1: no, functional indexes and constraints were added in 4.0.1, and there is no (feasible) way to mimic these.

Comment: Any other way of doing it without UniqueConstraint ? I am sure it woiuld be. Due to some reasons, I can't upgrade my Django.